# How do I stop zipping a folder?

Tags: c#, .net, zip, cancellation-token

I want to zip a **folder** but also want an option to stop it during the zip.
I think that the best thing for me would be to pass a `CancellationToken` to the method so I can cancel it out of the method at any time.

The `System.IO.Compression` provides us a method for the zip but can not undo it (we wait for the end and then delete the zip):

```cs
string startPath = @"<path-to-folder>";
string zipPath = @"<path-to-output>\MyFileZip.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath); //can't pass a CancellationToken
```

Comment: You'll probably have to create your own directory zipping method, rather than relying on this helper method.

Comment: Further to the advice above, you'll have to create a `ZipArchive` and then add `ZipEntries` to it yourself. You can then check for a cancellation request before you create each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like was said in the comments you need to create your own ZIP file generator. Here is example:

```
public static class ZipFileExtension
{
    public static void CreateFromDirectory(string fromPath, string outputFileName, CancellationToken cancelBuild)
    {
        var files = new DirectoryInfo(fromPath).GetFiles();
        using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                foreach (var fileInfo in files)
                {
                    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileInfo.FullName, fileInfo.Name);
                    if (cancelBuild.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (cancelBuild.IsCancellationRequested && File.Exists(outputFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(outputFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
ZipFileExtension.CreateFromDirectory("C:\\inputFolder","output.zip",CancellationToken.None);
```